# how to create a new statement in dart with intellij Dart plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-plugin, intellij-platform-psi

```
final PsiElementFactory factory = JavaPsiFacade.getInstance(project).getElementFactory();
PsiStatement useMemoStatement = instance.createStatementFromText("int a = plus(b + c);", null);
```

in java we can create a statement like above.
i cloned flutter plugin and i'm adding a new intention(alt + enter) function,
but idon't know how to create new statement in dart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this question answered here [How to create dart statement with dart plugin? #4329](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/4329)
thanks to flutter plugin team ♥